# gcloud dataproc clusters list --region=us-central1 shows list of 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, dataproc

We have two clusters in that region however when I runt his command in cli, it returns list of 0
Even when I describe the cluster I do not see "region" but the zone is us-central1-a.

Ultimately I am trying to stop the cluster but since region is not available, the command fails with error:
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.stop) NOT_FOUND: Not found: Cluster projects//regions/us-central1/clusters/

How do I find the region?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Dataproc cluster, you are required to provide the region using the `--region` parameter.

You may also consider using auto zone rather than selecting a zone manually with `--zone` option. [See docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/auto-zone)

When listing the Dataprocs in the region, as an example the zone shows as "`us-central1-a`" or "`us-central1-f`", you should ignore the last 2 characters i.e.: "**-a**" or "**-f**" to get the region where cluster was created.

Then, to stop your Dataproc cluster you need to provide only the region.

e.g.: `gcloud dataproc clusters stop <cluster_name> --region us-central1`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like while creating a cluster, you have an option to pick zonal (single zone or multi-zone) or regional and in our case it was created using zonal and hence no region.